# Can anyone explain this snippet froma a stored procedure i have picked up

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This may be a silly question. I have picked up a stored procedure and I am no so sure what this part is doing. It is right at the beginning just under the variables that have been declared.

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------ */
SELECT @DW_InsDate = DW_InsDate
  FROM [aud].[ExtractTime]
 WHERE [CurrentRecordYN] = 'X';
-- 'X' is the transitory state
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

One after the other (for each record fulfilling the condition) assigns to the variable value from the `DW_InsDate` column, so finally in the variable `@DW_InsDate` we find the last record that meets the condition (the last record, i.e. the last value from the `DW_InsDate` column)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "last record" in a table.

Comment: I used this phrase to explain, I do not know how I could call it otherwise to be understandable @GordonLinoff any suggestions ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am sure that the last record here means the latest record (assuming that the [aud].[ExtractTime] is a date/time historical table)

Comment: @ShoaibMaroof The value assigned will be taken from some undetermined row matching the criteria. It might "appear" that a particular row is used when testing with small tables and lightly loaded machines. Such assumptions will eventually be disproved in a live production environment. If there is an assumption that only one row will match the criteria, then it is better to use a set statement (e.g., set @ DW_InsDate = (select ...);) Why? This will generate an error when multiple rows are found.

Comment: @SMor I understand the point you make about the SELECT, but with a TOP 1 you are ensured to get a single record back. Also, would SET not be used when assigning a value from a function to the variable ?

Answer (score -2):

Here you are trying to assign the value of the `DW_InsDate` column of the `ExtractTime` table after filtering `CurrentRecordYN` column value with 'X';

You will have to face error if there are multiple records. you need to try code below if you have multiple entries.

```
set @DW_InsDate =select top 1 DW_InsDate
  FROM [aud].[ExtractTime]
 WHERE [CurrentRecordYN] = 'X';
```

Comment: No error, check : `DECLARE @t INT

CREATE TABLE #tmp (id INT)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (3)

SELECT @t= id FROM #tmp
select @t

DROP TABLE #tmp`

Comment: Passing a dataset with multiple rows to a variable won't generate an error, it'll simply assign every value (in order) to the variable, meaning that its final value will be the value of whatever was in the last row.

Comment: it depends upon the @DW_InsDate variable, if it is a table then we should insert data into it, I assume that is is not a table variable. as per my opinion, many new developers make mistakes by forgetting to use TOP for fetch one record.

Comment: The syntax `SELECT @DW_InsDate = DW_InsDate FROM...` would fail if `@DW_InsDate` was a table variable. (Give `DECLARE @i table (i int);
SELECT @i = i
FROM (VALUES(1),(2)) V(i);
SELECT *
FROM @i;` a try) You would have to use an `INSERT` statement then.